# What process was used to produce heavy water at the Norsk Hydro plant in Vemork Norway?

Tags: water, history, isotopes

All references I have browsed for this Norsk Hydro plant mention very little on the actual heavy water production process used.  I understand that this plant was adjacent to a power station that had a high electrical power output by exploiting a 138 meter water drop of dammed river.  My guess is that therefore some kind of electrolysis was used.  Other references mentioned heavy water as side product of ammonia production.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: Is there something in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_heavy_water_sabotage#Heavy_water_production) that you're unclear about?

Comment: Wikipedia is blocked in the country I am at right now.

Comment: There are other questions about this plant that are not closed or even on hold that are even less relevant to physics than mine.  Since my question deals with isotope separation, it is more physics than chemistry.

Comment: I believe they used [electrolysis](http://www.chemistryworks.net/2013/09/heavy-water.html).